# Clarification on relative xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want an xpath which represents the element 2 w.r.t element 1, as shown in the picture below. Can I build it using following-sibling?

Any help appreciated.

[image]

```html
<div id="leads_data" class="uk-width-large-8-12 uk-container-center">
 <div class="md-card-list leads_cards_list">
  <ul class="">
   <li class="item-shown" style="margin: 40px -20px; min-height: 90px;">
 <div class="md-card-list-item-menu" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click',pos:'bottom-right'}">
  <span>12:35:22 PM</span>
  <a class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-wave waves-effect waves-button" onclick="showModal(446)" data-uk-modal="{ center:true }" href="#lead_info">Edit</a>
 </div>
 <div class="md-card-list-item-sender">
  <span>
   <i class="material-icons">face</i>
    CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="md-card-list-item-sender">
  <span>
   <i class="material-icons">call</i>
    +91-1119771441
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="md-card-list-item-subject">
  <span>
   <i class="material-icons">email</i>
    rnkntsoorh@jd.com
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="md-card md-card-list-item-content-wrapper uk-margin-top" onclick="showModal(446)" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="md-card-content leads_card_content">
   <div class="uk-text-large uk-margin-remove">
    <b>Remarks:</b>
     Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<br/>
</li>
```

I want to start with div having the text "CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO" and locate the div having the text "Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC".

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots when your post your problems code. Post the properly formatted text, please

Comment: You need to share your HTML code or website URL instead of screenshot if really you want a solution....

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the question. Kindly do the needful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `xPath` :-

```
//span[contains(.,'CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO')]/parent::div/following::div[contains(.,'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC')][last()]
```

or

```
//span[contains(.,'CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO')]/parent::div/following::div[contains(.,'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC') and contains(@class, 'uk-text-large uk-margin-remove')]
```

or

```
//span[contains(.,'CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[contains(.,'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC')]/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'uk-text-large uk-margin-remove')]
```

or

```
//span[contains(.,'CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[contains(.,'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC')]/div/div
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thanks that helped Saurabh... :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ways described by Saurabh gaur you can also use `following-sibling` to locate the desired element.

```
.//span[text()='CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO']/../following-sibling::div[position()=3]//div[contains(.,'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC')]
```

or

```
.//span[text()='CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO']/../following-sibling::div[position()=3]/div/div[contains(text(),'Some remarks of TSYNTORSAC']
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the element containing the desired text instead of using `following`:

```
//li[div[normalize-space(.)='face CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO']]/div[last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
//div[contains(@class,'md-card-list-item-sende') and contains(.,'CDYCUQYGNKYNFNFCWOUO')]/following::div[contains(@class,'md-card-list-item-content') and descendant::b[contains(.,'Remarks')]]
```